# Calculate from one cell in first row

Tags: r

This is probably an easy fix but I'm struggling with something easy in Excel but not so obvious in R. Have done a fair bit of Googling and searching here but no success.

My data (df) looks like this:

```
    Amount   Amount
1    25       100
2    33       ?
3    18       ?
4    27       ?
```

What I want to do is put a formula in cell B3 which is B2 + A3.

Whilst this is simple to do in r, where I'm struggling is to put B2 as a base figure and then to work from there. Therefore, B3 would be 133, B4 151 etc.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check `?cumsum`, you need something like `cumsum(c(100, df$Amount[2:4]))`

Comment: Thank you - a bit of fiddling and it worked.

Comment: @RonakShah. Why not post an answer? I don't remember seeing exactly this Q before.

Comment: I moved the start figure out of the data so that the first row of the column reflected the cumsum function `100 + cumsum(df$Amount)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(Amount = c(25,33,18, 27))
df

#  Amount
#1     25
#2     33
#3     18
#4     27
```

and you want to start your cumulative sum from 100, you could do

```
df$cumsumAmount <- cumsum(c(100, df$Amount[2:nrow(df)]))

df

#  Amount cumsumAmount
#1     25          100
#2     33          133
#3     18          151
#4     27          178
```